# How to understand "if(!($value%2))" in php code?

Tags: php

I am just coding in PHP but not understand below-mentioned coding so please help for understanding coding simply

```
$new_array=array(100,101,61,1075);
foreach($new_array as $value){
if(!($value%2)){
   continue;
 }
}
```

Comment: `$value%2` gives the remainder of `$value / 2` and `!` means NOT, so if the remainder is `0`, meaning `$value` is evenly disible by 2, an even number. Commonly written `if($value % 2 === 0){`

Comment: @FaizalShaikh could you please mark the best nswer as the final answer

Answer (score 1):

You may read this condition as "is number `$value` can be divided by 2 without a remainder?"

Answer (score 0):

**foreach**
this is a Array method which we can use to execute on each element of the array. So in your code
    `foreach($new_array as $value){`

This will assign

```
$value[0] = 100
$value[1] = 101
$value[2] = 61
$value[3] = 1075
```

Then in php **%** mean modules. When this operator is used within two numbers it will output the remainder after deviding first number from second number.See below examples.

```
5%5 = 0
5%4 = 1
5%3 = 2
10%7 = 3
```

**($value%2)** 
In here each assigned values from array will be divided from 2 and check the remainder.

```
$value[0] = 100 => 100%2 = 0
$value[1] = 101 => 101%2 = 1
$value[2] = 61 => 61%2 = 1
$value[3] = 1075 => 1075%2 = 1
```

**(!($value%2))** After using **NOT** operator(!). This means that **($value%2)** should be false.It means that **($value%2)** should output a value equal to  0. You  can check and understand this code as below.

```
    <?php
$new_array=array(100,101,61,1075);
foreach($new_array as $value){
if(!($value%2)){
  echo($value."  " );
 }
}
?>
```

**Output =100**

```
  ?php
$new_array=array(100,101,61,1075);
foreach($new_array as $value){
if(($value%2)){
  echo($value." , " );
 }
}
?>
```

**Output = 101 , 61 , 1075 ,**

So hope you can have a idea with this. 
For more just follow this links.[click here to know about modules operator via official document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)
Thanks